# Mathematical typography for input of derivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, formatting

I prefer to enter mathematical expressions using typography that closely mirrors traditional mathematical typography... as for instance is found in a scientific paper or textbook.  Thus if I see the term $t^2$ in a printed equation, I type as input

```
t^2
```

rather than, say,

```
Power[t,2]
```

(Actually, the best version is `t CNTRL^ 2`, which sets the exponent elevated and smaller.)

I find this helps me (and students) more accurately translate printed equations into `Input` form and non-incidentally think more like a mathematician, see the structure of equations, ensure proper syntax, and so forth (even if it might require a few extra keystrokes).

To this end I'd like to find the most "mathematical style" input for a derivative, such as $\frac{d t^2}{dt}$ or $\frac{d}{dt} t^2$, rather than the "computer style" of `D[t^2,t]`.

One can use the ***Basic math*** palette and insert a partial derivative symbol with subscript, `ESC pd ESC CNTRL-`, and then enter, `t` in the subscript box and `t^2` in the line to get the equivalent of $\partial_t t^2$.  Indeed, when this term is entered (interpreted), the proper solution, `2 t` is computed.  Fine.

But I'd prefer an even more "mathematical" typography for input.  One that uses `(\[DifferentialD]/\[DifferentialD]t)t^2` (properly rendered), something visually equivalent to $\frac{d t^2}{dt}$ or $\frac{d}{dt} t^2$, as mentioned above.

Alas, all my efforts to typeset an input with a "traditional" ratio may *appear* proper, but none get interpreted so that the derivative is actually computed.  Even clicking on the nice ratio version in the **Basic math** palette fails to be interpreted.

In short:  How do I typeset a traditional ratio form of a derivative *and* later have it properly interpreted (and thus computed)?

Moreover, I don't want to write a term in text form and then convert it to TraditionalForm.  For instance, I don't want to type `Power[t,2]` and then convert it using TraditionalForm.  That defeats the whole point.

To clarify using a more complex example:  The following are two computationally equivalent inputs of a complex term:

[image: equivalent terms]

I find it much easier to interpret the bottom input.  A single character missing in the upper, text-based input is hard to find.

So it is clear how to do this with integrals (and summations...).  How to do it with a derivative expressed in the traditional form of a ratio?

Clear?

(Note that the "mathematical typography" of an integral is interpreted properly.)

Comment: Convert the expressions you are writing to `TraditionalForm` and evaluate. e.g. `\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\((
\*SuperscriptBox[\(t\), \(2\)])\)\)`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  `D[t^2,t] //TraditionalForm` or `TraditionalForm[D[t^2,t]` evaluates to the solution directly ($2t$), but I want instead to see the input in the proper "mathematical" form *before* I enter/interpret it.  (Am I missing something here?). And your version does not give the *ratio* form (just the partial derivative sign with subscript I mentioned in my question.)

Comment: This doesn't fix the desired input part of your question but it will display (pretty much) what you want:  `Inactivate[D[t^2, t]] // TraditionalForm`.  Then you just have to use `Activate` at some point to have it evaluated.  Maybe that could be a function placed into a palette.

Comment: @JimB:  Thanks, but as I pointed out in my comment, having the student type `D[t^2,t]` is precisely what I want to *AVOID*.  It defeats the whole purpose of exploiting the syntax constraints and such.  Example:  enter a definite integral sign from the **Basic math** palette.  You see the slots and such.  You enter the variables accordingly.  Your approach demands the user type text *perfectly*, in order to see the mathematical term.  *THAT* is what is to be avoided.  Clear?

Comment: I looked at all the pallettes and you are right, there does not seem to be one to enter $\frac{d f(t)}{dt}$ type of input.  It will be nice to have one.

Comment: I am confused. In the menu bar at the top select ClassRoom Assistant from the Palettes menu item. In the Basic Commands section, click the ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhOcu.png) tab (it is about in the center of the palette), and then click the space where you want the blank form and then click the ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dftmt.png) symbol. At that time you can fill in the variable and the function.

Comment: For derivative use the the one that looks like ![∂](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPLNC.png).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Notation Package](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/tutorial/NotationSymbolizeAndInfixNotation.html).

*The code below looks huge because it is written with box forms so that you can copy&paste it correctly (without interpretation) to the notebook.*

```
Cell[BoxData[{
 RowBox[{"Notation", "[", 
  RowBox[{
   TemplateBox[{
     RowBox[{
       FractionBox["\[DifferentialD]", 
        RowBox[{"\[DifferentialD]", "x_"}]], "y_"}]},
    "NotationTemplateTag"], " ", "⟹", " ", 
   TemplateBox[{
     RowBox[{"D", "[", 
       RowBox[{"y_", ",", "x_"}], "]"}]},
    "NotationTemplateTag"]}], "]"}], "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
 RowBox[{"Notation", "[", 
  RowBox[{
   TemplateBox[{
     RowBox[{
       FractionBox[
        SuperscriptBox["\[DifferentialD]", "n_"], 
        RowBox[{"\[DifferentialD]", 
          SuperscriptBox["x_", "n_"]}]], "y_"}]},
    "NotationTemplateTag"], " ", "⟹", " ", 
   TemplateBox[{
     RowBox[{"D", "[", 
       RowBox[{"y_", ",", 
         RowBox[{"{", 
           RowBox[{"x_", ",", "n_"}], "}"}]}], "]"}]},
    "NotationTemplateTag"]}], "]"}], "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
 RowBox[{"Notation", "[", 
  RowBox[{
   TemplateBox[{
     FractionBox[
      RowBox[{"\[DifferentialD]", "y_"}], 
      RowBox[{"\[DifferentialD]", "x_"}]]},
    "NotationTemplateTag"], " ", "⟹", " ", 
   TemplateBox[{
     RowBox[{"D", "[", 
       RowBox[{"y_", ",", "x_"}], "]"}]},
    "NotationTemplateTag"]}], "]"}], "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
 RowBox[{"Notation", "[", 
  RowBox[{
   TemplateBox[{
     FractionBox[
      RowBox[{
        SuperscriptBox["\[DifferentialD]", "n_"], " ", "y_"}], 
      RowBox[{"\[DifferentialD]", 
        SuperscriptBox["x_", "n_"]}]]},
    "NotationTemplateTag"], " ", "⟹", " ", 
   TemplateBox[{
     RowBox[{"D", "[", 
       RowBox[{"y_", ",", 
         RowBox[{"{", 
           RowBox[{"x_", ",", "n_"}], "}"}]}], "]"}]},
    "NotationTemplateTag"]}], "]"}]}], "Input"
]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh perfect... *perfect*!  I didn't know about the Notation package, and see it is very helpful.  ($+1, \checkmark$).  I just hope WRI incorporates this trick into subsequent versions of *Mathematica* as it is so valuable.