# CaputoD as Caputo Fractional Derivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, custom-notation, notation

I hope everyone is doing well. I have a question about mathematica that I have attached here. If you look into the attached picture, then you can see the Derivative of unknown function f[t] in mathematica is represented as f'[t] but the fractional derivative of f[t] does not have any notation. How can I define it? Secondly, if the unknown function involve in the expression, the fractional derivative does not work for whole expression.
[image]

Comment: What kind of notation do you want for `CaputoD`?

Comment: It is preferred to post the actual code formatted properly instead of screenshots

Comment: Any notation, like a^{\alpha}[t].

Comment: Actually, I was trying to add the code but I could not.  Please look at this and send me your valuable suggestions.

Comment: @MuhammadAamirAli See the instructions here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13226/27951. It's hard to help if we can't play with your actual code. If you don't include the code, your question is likely to be close as "missing valid code".

Comment: I have only: `g[t_] := Sin[t] + a[t] + t + Exp[t] + c*b[t]; 
CaputoD[#, {t, 1/2}] & /@ g[t]`.

Comment: @MuhammadAamirAli, you can use [Notation package](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/tutorial/NotationSymbolizeAndInfixNotation.html) (see for example [Mathematical typography for input of derivative](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/272791/75628)).